# Java: using .contains but returns two values

Tags: java

I need my code to print toppings when characters are entered by user

For example: 'lpsh' would print into an array 'Large pizza, Pineapple, Spinach, Ham.

Problem example: 'm' would print both Medium pizza AND mozzarella.

I need it to only print one of the two if only one 'm' is entered, but also print both if two m's are entered, I'm a beginner to Java and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much. Unfinished code:

```
    String[] pizza = new String[7];
    pizza[2] = "h";
    pizza[3] = "m";
    pizza[4] = "o";
    pizza[5] = "p";
    pizza[6] = "s";

    String[] pizzaSize = new String[2];
    pizzaSize[0] = "m";
    pizzaSize[1] = "l";


    while (true) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a Pizza Order: ");                                //Request user input and declares order
        String order = input.nextLine();
        List<String> arrayTest = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (order.contains(pizzaSize[0])) {
            multiplier = 1;
            pizzaPrice += 4;
            arrayTest.add("Medium Pizza");
            arrayTest.remove("Large Pizza");
        }
        if (order.contains(pizza[3])) {
            arrayTest.add("Mozzarella");
            pizzaPrice += 1.00 * multiplier;
        }}
```

Comment: Should the position of the letter determine how it is translated? For example, is an `m` in the first position always "medium", and an `m` in any other position always "mozzarella"?

Comment: for 'm' looks like you are doing multiple activity (size + cheese) as your position determines the size why do you need the cheese activity processing for order = 'm'

Comment: Yep you're correct! the first character represents the size of the pizza (l or m), the rest are the toppings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possible solution

In order to solve your problem, use [`string.startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `string.contains()`:

```
if (order.startsWith(pizzaSize[0])) {
    /* medium */
}
else if (order.startsWith(pizzaSize[1])) {
    /* large */
}
else {
    /* unexpected input */
}
```

This works because the first letter always indicates the pizza size. You can stick to using `contains()` for the toppings.

### `pizza` Array

Second, what is going on with your `pizza` array? What about elements `0` and `1`?

```
String[] pizza = new String[7];
pizza[2] = "h";
pizza[3] = "m";
pizza[4] = "o";
pizza[5] = "p";
pizza[6] = "s";
```

### Some other notes

- Use *divide and conquer*: Split your task up into its logical parts, then tackle each individually. This will make your life easier. If it helps, do it on paper first!
- You don't need to create a `Scanner` for every iteration of the loop. The same goes for most of the other variables declared at the beginning of the loop. Try to declare those before the loop.
- Try to give your variables meaningful names. How is anyone supposed to understand or remember the purpose of `arrayTest`?
- You might want to improve your code by using [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) or a [custom `Topping` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), unless you don't feel comfortable using those techniques yet.

Answer (score 0):

Remark: put this line at top of your validations:

```
if (order.equals("quit")) {
    break;
}
```

Try `if(order.indeOf(pizza[3])) == 0` to get shure m is at the first position or try to use regex to validate the input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    String[] pizza = new String[7];
    pizza[2] = "h";
    pizza[3] = "m";
    pizza[4] = "o";
    pizza[5] = "p";
    pizza[6] = "s";

    while (true) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String order = input.nextLine();
        int pizzaPrice = 0;
        double multiplier = 0;
        System.out.println(pizzaPrice);
        List<String> arrayTest = new ArrayList<>();

        if (order.equals("quit")) {
            break;
        }


        Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("(?<size>[m|l])(?<toppings>[hmops]*)");
        Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(order);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String size = matcher.group("size");
            switch (size) {
                case "m":
                    multiplier = 1;
                    pizzaPrice += 4;
                    arrayTest.add("Medium Pizza");
                    arrayTest.remove("Large Pizza");
                    break;
                case "l":
                    arrayTest.add("Large Pizza");
                    arrayTest.remove("Medium Pizza");//add to string instead so printed in format
                    multiplier = 1.5;
                    pizzaPrice += 5;
                    break;
                default:
                    //TODO unknown pizza
                    break;
            }

            String toppings = matcher.group("topping");
            if (toppings.contains(pizza[2])) {
                arrayTest.add("Ham");
                pizzaPrice += 1.40 * multiplier;
            }
            if (toppings.contains(pizza[3])) {
                arrayTest.add("Mozzarella");
                pizzaPrice += (1.00 * multiplier);
            }
            if (toppings.contains(pizza[4])) {
                arrayTest.add("Olives");
            }
            if (toppings.contains(pizza[5])) {
                arrayTest.add("Pineapple");
            }
            if (toppings.contains(pizza[6])) {
                arrayTest.add("Spinach");
                // integer = integer + price of Spinach
            }
            System.out.println(pizzaPrice);
            System.out.println(arrayTest);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order is going to be entered as single character representations of their ingredients, why not just treat the input as a char array instead of a string?

```
char[] charArray = new char[100];
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int actualBuffered = buffer.read(charArray,0,100);
```

and then you can just analyze the first element as size, and the rest as ingredients.

```
if(charArray[0] == 'l'))
    //set size large
else if...

for(int i=1; i<charArray.length; i++)
{
    if(charArray[i] == 'm')
    {
        //moz option added
    }
}
```