# Switches comparing characters

Tags: java, hashmap

im having issues with converting my string input to a character, and comparing the character to a switch. I want the user to enter a order of the size of pizza followed by upto 4 toppings that looks like "lop"(large olive pineapple) for example, and i want to split and compare the string into characters so i can output the order as "medium pizza with olives, pineapple" (pineapple on pizza, i know heresy) and have the total at the end.

Am i on the right track for this kind of task, or would it be easier to use an array, split the array input and compare each letter of the string rather than using characters and hashmaps?

My code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Exercise_1{
    public static void pizzaServiceA(String args[]){

        HashMap <Character, String> Toppings = new Hashmap <Character, String>();

        //pizza
        Toppings.put('m', "meduim");
        Toppings.put('l', "large");

        //topping
        Toppings.put('h', "ham");
        Toppings.put('m', "mozzerella");
        Toppings.put('o', "olives");
        Toppings.put('p', "pineapple");
        Toppings.put('s', "spinach");

        Toppings.put('H', "ham");
        Toppings.put('M', "mozzerella");
        Toppings.put('O', "olives");
        Toppings.put('P', "pineapple");
        Toppings.put('S', "spinach");


        HashMap <Character, Double> Prices = new Hashmap <Character, Double>();


        //pizza price 
        Prices.put('m', 4.00);
        Prices.put('l', 5.00);

        //topping price medium
        Prices.put('h', 1.40);
        Prices.put('m', 1.00);
        Prices.put('o', 0.80);
        Prices.put('p', 1.00);
        Prices.put('s', 1.20);

        //topping price large
        Prices.put('H', 2.10);
        Prices.put('M', 1.50);
        Prices.put('O', 1.20);
        Prices.put('P', 1.50);
        Prices.put('S', 1.20);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter order: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        Character order = Character.valueOf(input);

        Double totalPrice = 0.0;

        switch (order){

            case 'm': 
                    totalPrice += 4.00;
                    System.out.println("Medium pizza ");
                    break;

            case 'l': 
                    totalPrice += 5.00;
                    System.out.println("Large pizza ");
                    break;
        }

    }
}
```

edit: ok so this is what i have come up wth now (still using the hashmaps but discarding the switches

```
System.out.println("Enter a pizza order: ");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String orders = reader.nextLine();
    Char[] orderLetters = orders.toCharArray();


    String fullOrder = "";
    Double fullPrice = 0.0;


    //check if sequence enters it more than 5 characters

    if (orderLetters.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println("Quitting.");
            System.exit(0);
        } 

    else if (!(orderLetters[0].equals('l')))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of your pizza, m or l");

    }

    else if (!(orderLetters[0].equals('m')))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of your pizza, m or l");
    }


    for(Character orderLetters : c.toCharArray())
    {
        Double price = Prices.get(orderLetters);
        fullPrice += price;

        Character type = Toppings.get(orderLetters);
        if(type == 'm' || type == 'l')
        {
            fullOrder += type + " pizza with ";
        }
        else
        {
            fullOrder += type + ",";
        }


    }
    fullOrder += fullPrice;
    System.out.printf("%.2f", "£", fullOrder);

}
```

Comment: Good question so far but please include the real output and your expected output.

Comment: I don't see where you split the character and put them all though?

Comment: Im not splitting the characters at the moment, i assume its the same as splitting a string though?

Comment: Not sure this would be within the scope of your assignment and/or skill, but my first impulse would be to create a `Topping` class that holds all the required information (`id` for the letter identifying the topping, `name` for the actual name, `price` for the price, ...).

Comment: Also, you can treat Strings as arrays of characters - in other words, you coul loop through your input. And one more thing: not sure if it helps any, but I think this guy got the same assignment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056756/java-using-contains-but-returns-two-values

Comment: @johncliffe at the moment when i build it throws an error with incompatible types string cannot be converted to a char

Comment: Cinnamon, you can't convert a String to a char, but to an array of chars via [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, ill try that out thanks\

Comment: @Cinnamon char[] characterArray = input.toCharArray();

Answer (score 0):

> Am i on the right track for this kind of task, or would it be easier
>   to use an array, split the array input and compare each letter of the
>   string rather than using characters and hashmaps?

It depends. Having an input API that contains all data may be clumsy to use for the client. And if he wants to add something else because he has forgotten, he cannot. He has to start again from the beginning his order.

The way you are using seems ok.
Nevertheless, big switch is harder to maintain.
You should favor in your Map the use of Objects that have structured data.

```
    Character order = Character.valueOf(input);
    switch (order){

        case 'm': 
                totalPrice += 4.00;
                System.out.println("Medium pizza ");
                break;

        case 'l': 
                totalPrice += 5.00;
                System.out.println("Large pizza ");
                break;
    }
```

could be :

```
    Set<Character> toppingKeysAccepted = Arrays.asList(toppings.keySet());
    ...
    Character order = input.charAt(0); 
    if (toppingKeysAccepted.contains(order)){
          Pizza pizza = pizzas.get(order);               
          totalPrice + = pizza.getPrice();
          System.out.println(pizza.getText());
    }

    else{ //processing error case

    }
```

As a side note, you may convert a `String` that contains a single char to a char by doing `char c = string.charAt(0);`

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code:

**1. The hash**

Your are using a hashmap from characters to strings and this is ok, but each character can have only one output (you can't have 'm' point both to 'medium' and to 'mozzerella').

This can be fixed in 2 ways:

1. Use 2 maps (doesn't have to be hashmap, you can also use treemap). One for sizes and one for toppings.
2. Change the way you look at characters. Make 'm' mean only one thing and do so for each letter. No letter can have more than one meaning.

I personally think the first way is better. The sizing and the toppings shouldn't be on the same variable, they are not connected in any way.

**2. The way you read the input**
First of all you can use `read()` instread of `readLine()`.
Second of all you need to look at your input as a string and not as a character. Then use `str.charAt(index)` to read characters from your string.

---

## A General Flow of My Solution to the Problem

1. Read an input string from the user
2. Using a simple switch determine the size of the pizza (this is a very limited check and so let's keep it simple.
3. Iterate over all remaining letters in the string and for each one use a toppings hash to add to the price

After all of that you are left with the price after evaluating the whole string (both the size and the toppings).

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Assuming this is the same assignment as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056756/java-using-contains-but-returns-two-values), then `m` can have indeed two meanings - if you also take its position into account.

Comment: Yes, but this has nothing to do with hash...
It is indeed another way to solve the problem (which I kind of included in my solution to the problem)